# Как работает эта небольшая функция?

Tags: javascript

```js
function superFunJankTime() {
    var start = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() - start < 1000);
    setTimeout(superFunJankTime, 50);
} 
superFunJankTime();
```

Comment: Я так понимаю тут просто назначение кучи таймаутов которые и вызывают тормоза. Просто непонятно зачем такие сложности с `while`

Comment: кучи таймаутов тут нет, просто пустой `while` loop

Comment: да, да понял уже. весёлая штука

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function superFunJankTime() {
    // узнаем текущее время
    var start = Date.now();
    // а теперь секунду крутимся в этом цикле
    // обратите внимание на точку с запятой
    while (Date.now() - start < 1000);
     // и запустим эту же функцию через 50мс
    // надо же другому коду чуточку поработать
    setTimeout(superFunJankTime, 50);
}
// первый раз запускаем ручками. 
superFunJankTime();
```

Comment: Точку с запятой я и не заметил.

Comment: Имеется ввиду другой код из главного потока.

Answer (score 1):

```
function superFunJankTime() {
    var start = Date.now();// замерить настоящее время 
    while (Date.now() - start < 1000); //гонять пустой while loop в течении 1 секунды
    setTimeout(superFunJankTime, 50);//запустить ту же функцию через 50 мс
}
```

Comment: **рекурсивно** запустить? честно?

Comment: а да, не рекурсивно